# Windows10mobileにおけるFTPClientの作成

Tags: c#, windows-10, ftp, win-universal-app, mobile

VS2017にてWindows10mobile上で動作するUWPアプリケーション（C#）を作成しています。

BackgroudDownloaderを使用してFTPサーバーからファイルを取得する処理を行っているのですが、DownloadOperationのステータスに"PausedNoNetwork"が返ってきており、ダウンロード処理が進みません。

デスクトップアプリ(x86ビルド）では問題なくファイルの取得ができております。
モバイルアプリだとBackgroundDownloaderが対応していないのでしょうか。

```
Uri urlWithCredential = requestUri;
if (credential != null)
{
     // URIをMSDNに従いftp://UserName:Password/path の形式に整える 
    urlWithCredential = new Uri(
                            requestUri.ToString().ToLower().Replace(@"ftp://",
                            string.Format(@"ftp://{0}:{1}@",
                            EncodeUrl(credential.UserName),
                            EncodeUrl(credential.Password)
                            )));
}

BackgroundDownloader downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
DownloadOperation download = downloader.CreateDownload(urlWithCredential, targetFile);

// ダウンロードの状態を把握するためコールバック関数を設定
return download.StartAsync().AsTask(progressCallback);
```

OS:Windows10 Mobile
ビルド：10.0.10586.11
ネットワーク:wifi（ローカルネットワーク）
ターゲットバージョン：14393
最小バージョン：10240

> > 追記
> >     色々と検討してみましたが、Windows10 mobileだとBackgroundDownloaderが意図したように動作しないようです。
> >     [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783103/backgrounddownloader-is-not-working-for-windows-10-mobile-uwp]
> >     StreamSocketを利用して地道にFTPサーバーと通信すれば、ファイルをダウンロードできました。
> >     Backgroundでの動作は必須ではないので、今回はSocket通信にて実装を進めることにします。

Comment: [マルチポストをされる場合](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2419/4236)は各サイトで得られた情報を質問者さんが他サイトにも随時展開してください。 https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ja-JP/f93289cf-f145-4cd5-bb7e-bddcf2a2dd78/windows10-mobileftp-client?forum=winstoreapp

Comment: 承知いたしました。各サイトの情報は共有させていただきます。